How to get only one file from Git repository?
In a CMakeLists.txt, I retrieve a Git repository with the commands:
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  CMakeScripts
  GIT_REPOSITORY <Git repository>
  GIT_TAG        <hash code>
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(CMakeScripts)
FetchContent_GetProperties(CMakeScripts SOURCE_DIR CMakeScripts_SOURCE_DIR)

But actually, I need only one file:
include(${CMakeScripts_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Utils.cmake)

How to avoid retrieving the full repository?

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/600079/6330106 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42902162/6330106. Among the answers, partial clone and git archive --remote are lightweight solutions. But they rely on the server. Some hosting services may not support them. If this Utils.cmake is maintained by you, you can tag its blob and then fetch the tag only to get its content.

I think a shallow-clone and sparse checkout would allow you to get a single file... though I still think it's not like featherweight.

@ElpieKay Utils.cmake is maintained by me. What do you mean by "tag its blob" ?

Create a tag on a version of the file. Suppose the path in the repository is cmake/Utils.cmake. You can tag its version in a revision by git tag foo <rev>:cmake/Utils.cmake. The rev is a commit-ish or a ref. Push the tag to the remote repository and you can run git fetch <remote> foo && git show foo to get its content.

I didn't know it was possible to tag only one file. Thanks.

@ElpieKay does the fetch get the whole commit or just the blob?

@Oodini It's also possible to tag a tree object which represents a folder. git fetch <remote> +refs/tags/foo:refs/tags/foo && git show foo is less error-prone.

@evolutionxbox Just the blob.
